# Can't use innerhtml or select nodes, returns null

Tags: javascript, dom, null, innerhtml, getelementsbytagname

After multiple hours of searching, I haven't found a solution to this yet. every time I run this code:

```
var output = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

var array = [];

for(var x = 0; x < output.length; x++){
    array.push(output[i])
    };

console.log(array);
```

all that I get in the console is:

```
[];
```

All I am trying to do is manipulate the inner html of one of the nodes (node #4 to be specific). I have also tried this:

```
var output = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[4];

output.innerHTML='hello world';
```

which just returns: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined`. Any help would be much appreciated.

I should also mention that using `querySelector` or `getElementById` and targeting the specific div only returns null.

Comment: are you doing this after page load/dom ready?

Comment: are you sure you are doing this after page load ?

Comment: do you load the js resource in head? try to move the js code to the bottom of the body

Comment: the js source is in the body but at the top, so I will try moving it to the bottom. As for running the code after the page load, I am not so I will try that as well.

Comment: Wow, this solved the problem. Thanks! I didnt realize that having the script tag at the top of the page could cause any issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself.

In your for loop, you are defining x as the iterator, but you are using output[i]. i hasn't been defined. Use output[x].

Also, to get the fourth element, you want the element with index 3. Since indexing starts at zero, the first element would be 0. The fourth would be 3.

Comment: oops. well, that still has not solved the problem, but thank you for pointing that out for me. 

Also, the node I am targeting is actually the 4 including the first index of 0, so technically i guess I would be targeting the 5th node.